# How to see if an element in an array includes a character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have an array with names in it

```
var arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"];
```

I have to come up with a output where if "+" is the first character of an element (not including the first element) in my array it has to return/console.log/alert the first element and the other elements that have "+" as the first character.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what have you tried ? A simple for loop should do the trick. you can look into `.startsWith()` function of strings to check if it is a '+' and do the necessary logic. You could also write a `.filter()` function to loop through and get only the elements with a '+'

Comment: you can try arr[x][0] it gives you first character

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `filter()` and `startsWith()`

```js
var arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"];
var r = arr.filter((i, idx) => idx == 0 || i.startsWith('+'));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: How do I add the first element of the array to the console.log portion?

Comment: @KarlaJensen, you can use index to return the first element along with `||` to return the other elements:)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the items and take the first one plus all strings with plus prefix.

```js
var array = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"],
    allPlusesWithFirst = array.filter((s, i) => !i || s.startsWith('+'));

console.log(allPlusesWithFirst);
```

Comment: It won't work if multiple elements have plus in front.

Comment: also possible: `array.slice(1)` to omit the first element

Comment: @NikhilGoyal, the question is a bit unclear ... please see edit,

Comment: @VLAZ but then how would I return the whole element that includes a "+"?

Comment: @KarlaJensen, please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike all the other answers proposing `startsWith` (which obviously only matches if the string starts with the character), I want to suggest using the `String.includes` function:

```
["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"].find(x => x.includes("+"));
```

This will however always only return the first result that contains the string. A more robust solution would be:

```
["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"].filter(x => x.includes("+"));
```

Using the `filter` function we can find ALL items that match our condition within the `array`.

Comment: `.includes` can be used instead of `.indexOf`

Comment: You're right. Includes all performs better when searching for types as `NaN` and such. I've modified my answer.

Comment: how would `.includes` look?

Comment: @KarlaJensen I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```js
function requiredElements(arr) {
  const finalArr = arr.filter(curr => curr.startsWith('+'));
  
  if (finalArr.length === 0)
    return [];
  return [arr[0], ...finalArr];
}

var arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"];
console.log(requiredElements(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

String is array so, you can filter it by index:

```
var arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora"];

const newArr = arr.filter(item => item[0] === "+");
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

makes result only if any not-first element starts with '+', otherwise nothing.

```js
const result = [];
const arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora", '+Somebody'];
const allPluses = arr.slice(1).filter(e => e.startsWith('+'));
if (allPluses.length) {
  result.push(arr[0], ...allPluses);
  console.log(result);
//alert(result);
//return result; // if within a function
}
```

old es3 js version:

```js
var arr = ["Kim", "+Jane", "Dora", '+Somebody'];
var result = [arr[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0] === '+') {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
if (result.length > 1) {
  console.log(result);
//alert(result);
//return result; // if within a function
}
```